# React Circular Progressbar no repeat

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, react-hooks

I want to know how to make the loader of `React Circular Progressbar` only load once and no repeat the secuence.

I check all the documentation and there is no info about that, also the other components that create the animation didn't change the secuence.

Here is the example of the progress bar:
[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-violet-cxczd)

and here is the code in the app.js

```js
 <ChangingProgressProvider values={[0, percentage]}>
        {percentage => (
          <CircularProgressbar
            value={percentage}
            text={`${percentage}%`}
            styles={buildStyles({
              pathTransition:
                percentage === 0 ? "none" : "stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease 0s"
            })}
          />
        )}
      </ChangingProgressProvider>
```

and the code of the component for `CircularProgressbar`

```js
class ChangingProgressProvider extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    interval: 1000
  };

  state = {
    valuesIndex: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        valuesIndex: (this.state.valuesIndex + 1) % this.props.values.length
      });
    }, this.props.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.props.values[this.state.valuesIndex]);
  }
}

export default ChangingProgressProvider;
```

Answer (score 3):

the changingProgressProvider component is the one that keeps making it flash. if you just render the child component it loads once.
If you would like to have a delayed action just once. I would recommed you use setTimeout instead of setInterval. As the latter keeps repeating.

Comment: But in that case I lose the animation of the loading

Comment: checkout my edited answer, try changing setInterval to setTimeout